# using cookies with wget multilevel

Tags: php, linux, cookies, download, wget

I want to download all website that I already have access to.

I'm using wget:

```
### Log in to the server.  This can be done only once.                   
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
 --keep-session-cookies \
 --post-data 'email=myemail&password=mypass'\
 --delete-after \
 https://site/signin

### Now grab the page or pages we care about.
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
 --keep-session-cookies \
 --cookies=on \
 --mirror -p --html-extension --convert-links \
 https://site/dashboard
```

With the script above I can download all pages in:

`https://site/*`

But when I down into another "sub-folder" like:

`https://site/sub-folder/page.html`

I **can't** download "page.html" because wget doesn't recognize my login and password or my cookies (or forget it, I don't know what is going on).

So how can I download all multi-level content from this site?